# Trouble with Integration Tests on Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing

I'm currently working through Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial and have made it through Chapter 8. (Really liking the tutorial by the way!) Having finished chapter 8, I've run into a snag: the final integration test in users_spec.rb is succeeding on the FIRST run, but failing on the SECOND. (You can see the section of code I'm referring to here --> http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#sec:successful_signup The error that shows up in the console is this:

```
 1) Users signup success should make a new user
 Failure/Error: response.should have_selector('div.flash.success',...
```

However, when looking down through all the red HTML that gets spit out, I found this:

```
 <div id="error_explanation">
       <h2>1 error 
           prevented this user from being saved.</h2>
       <p>There were problems with the following fields:</p>
       <ul>
   <li>Email has already been taken</li>
       </ul>
   </div>
```

Thus it seems to me that the reason the test runs once, and THEN fails is that the user is still in the test DB on the second run and is therefore causing a validation failure due to duplicate e-mails. I can verify this by changing the e-mail in the test after each try. As long as I feed it a new email, the test won't fail.

In trying to troubleshoot further, I cloned the tutorial code from GitHub and setup the app. The tests run fine. I can run the whole suite, or just users_spec.rb as many times as I want - no problem. Actually, to be honest, (and I know this seems really odd) the code from GitHub  did fail a few times with the same email duplication error, but then after I rest the test db it worked fine. Believe me, I have done this in my app as well, but I still have the same issue. And yes, I've copied and pasted in the test code directly from the book, and also from the working GitHub code in an effort to weed out typos. No deal.

It would appear that there's something outside of the users_spec.rb file itself which is causing the problem, but I can't seem to find it. I'd love to move forward with the tutorial, but for the moment I'm stuck. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe check the `config.cache_classes` line in `config/environments/test.rb` and make sure it's `true`. You can also try hacking around the problem using a [factory sequence](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#code%3afactory_sequence).

Comment: Bingo. My `config.cache_classes` line was indeed set to false. I changed it to true and everything worked like a charm! I assume that when set to false, this means that the test db is not necessarily wiped between test runs? Thanks so much for taking the time to answer this!

Comment: I added that line to the book per [Peter Cooper's suggestion](http://www.rubyinside.com/how-to-rails-3-and-rspec-2-4336.html), but I've decided it probably does more harm than good and have removed it from the [current version](http://railstutorial.org/book).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to ensure that in your spec_helper.rb, you are cleaning out your database between runs. Your users_spec is assuming that the email will not exist, and your user validations are ensuring that it is unique.

This is a decent solution: https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner

Comment: Yep, that makes sense to me, but in the tutorial nothing is said about having to clear the DB between runs. And in fact, the tutorial code from GitHub runs fine as is. So I'm thinking there is something else missing.

Comment: As you said in your question, the github spec did fail in the same way a few times. I would go with the database cleaner, regardless of what the tutorial says, as it *will* fix the issue you are having.

Comment: Thanks Christopher, good point. I'll definitely keep that in mind.

Comment: FYI, I did install this gem and it worked as you said. I'll definitely keep that one in the toolbox. Turns out that Michael's solution (see answer above) worked also. Thanks again for the help!